# laravel adding custom another query into releatinship

Tags: laravel

in `laravel` i have this query which that work fine,

```
$months = Month::with(['lessons' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['files']);
}])->get();
```

in this query i have `$query->with(['files'])` which that is:

```
public function files()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LessonFiles::class);
}
```

i want to add this query for all of `$query->with(['files'])` rows which that have `lesson_file_key`:

```
LessonsView::whereLessonFileKey($lessonFile->lesson_file_key)->count()
```

it means i want to get count of each row of `$query->with(['files'])` in this query by adding above code, for example:

```
$months = Month::with(['lessons' => function ($query) {
    $req = $query->with(['files']);
    // for example using foreach on $req
    // LessonsView::whereLessonFileKey($req->lesson_file_key)->count()
}])->get();
```

**my models:**

```
class Month extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $hidden = ['id'];

    public function lessons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
    }

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MonthFiles::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Lesson extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $hidden = ['id', 'month_id', 'filename', 'file_url'];

    public function month()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Month::class);
    }

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LessonFiles::class);
    }
}
```

```
class LessonFiles extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $hidden = ['id', 'lesson_id', 'filename', 'file_url'];

    public function lesson()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lesson::class);
    }

    public function visits(){
        return $this->hasMany(LessonsView::class);
    }
}
```

```
class LessonsView extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $hidden = ['id','user_id','lesson_files_id','lesson_file_key','ip_address'];

    public function visitedLesson(){
        return $this->belongsTo(LessonFiles::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, **1)** Do `LessonFile` and `LessonView` both have a field called `lesson_file_key`? **2)** You're just wanting to include a count for how many `LessonView` have the same `letting_file_key` as `LessonFile`?

Comment: @Rwd for your first and second question my answer is yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this you could add a `views` relationship to you `LessonFiles` model, something like:

```
public function views()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LessonsView::class, 'lesson_file_key', 'lesson_file_key');
}
```

Then in your query you can use [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```
$months = Month::with([
    'lessons.files' => function ($query) {
        $query->withCount('views');
    },
])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `withCount` and `whereColumn` like this:

```php
$months = Month::with(['lessons' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['files' => function($q) {
       $q->withCount(['visits' => function($vq) {
           $vq->whereColumn('lesson_views.lesson_file_key', 'lesson_files.lesson_file_key')
        }]);       
    }]);
}])->get();
```